# Unit test: parallel execution doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am useing unit test in visual studio 2010.
I change the Execution element in Local.testSettings file to
  `<Execution hostProcessPlatform="MSIL" parallelTestCount="4">`
But all the tests running sequential.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx

Comment: I did everything like he wrote, but it's still dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve the problem:

- Step 1 - Open Local.testsettings => "data and diagnostics" tab, Disable all roles.
- Step 2 - **Reopen Visual studio**